# ruby string splitting problem

Tags: ruby, split

i have this string:
"asdasda=asdaskdmasd&asmda=asdasmda&ACK=Success&asdmas=asdakmsd&asmda=adasda"

i want to get the value after between the ACK and the & symbol, the value between the ACK and the & symbol can be changed...

thanks

i want the solution in ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require "cgi"

query_string = "asdasda=asdaskdmasd&asmda=asdasmda&ACK=Success&asmda=asdakmsd"
parsed_query_string = CGI.parse(query_string)
#=> { "asdasda" => ["asdaskdmasd"],
#     "asmda" => ["asdasmda", "asdakmsd"],
#     "ACK" => ["Success"] }

parsed_query_string["ACK"].first
#=> "Success"
```

If you also want to reconstruct the query string (especially together with the rest of a URL), I would recommend looking into the [`addressable`](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/) gem.

```
require "addressable/uri"

# Note the leading '?'
query_string = "?asdasda=asdaskdmasd&asmda=asdasmda&ACK=Success&asmda=asdakmsd"
parsed_uri = Addressable::URI.parse(query_string)
parsed_uri.query_values["ACK"]
#=> "Success"

parsed_uri.query_values = parsed_uri.query_values.merge("ACK" => "Changed")
parsed_uri.to_s
#=> "?ACK=Changed&asdasda=asdaskdmasd&asmda=asdakmsd"
# Note how the order has changed and the duplicate key has been removed due to
# Addressable's built-in normalisation.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "asdasda=asdaskdmasd&asmda=asdasmda&ACK=Success&asdmas=asdakmsd&asmda=adasda"
m = s.match /.*ACK=(.*?)&/
puts m[1]
```

and just for fun without regexp:

```
Hash[s.split("&").map{|p| p.split("=")}]["ACK"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"asdasda=asdaskdmasd&asmda=asdasmda&ACK=Success&asdmas=asdakmsd&asmda=adasda"[/ACK=([^&]*)&/]
$1 # => 'Success'
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick approach:

```
s = "asdasda=asdaskdmasd&asmda=asdasmda&ACK=Success&asdmas=asdakmsd&asmda=adasda"
s.gsub(/ACK[=\w]+&/,"ACK[changedValue]&")
   #=> asdasda=asdaskdmasd&asmda=asdasmda&ACK[changedValue]&asdmas=asdakmsd&asmda=adasda
```